# ASP.NET Token-based authorization is too long

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, authorization, owin

I have ASP.NET REST API service and it works pretty fast and fine, except of authorization, I'm using standart Token auth, based on Owin.Security, here is what it looks like:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,

        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

}

I didn't change anything, it is from template project and it works fine, except of time. It tooks about a 30 seconds to get back a bearer token from server.
I'm pretty new to ASP.NET development and I have no idea why it is so long, I have 10 users and 3 roles in my database, and I'm sure it can work faster, but don't know how

other rest request (POST, GET) works fast and fine, it takes 30 seconds only for /Token request

**well, I've republished my server solution and now it takes randomly from 3 to 30 seconds to get auth token, it is pretty strange behavior, isn't it?**

Comment: Can you look at the fiddler trace to see request to which Url(s) is taking 30 seconds or if this is distributed among different requests?

Comment: @ezile nono, it is just for token request myazuresite.com/Token
other works  fast and fine

Comment: @Greag.Deay Facing same issue, Authentication tooks more then 5 secords for log in. Did you find any way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar actually, I don't remember now, I saved auth token to local storage, so user doesn't need to do login everytime, and if I switch deploy mode from debug to release it goes a bit faster, but since ASP 5.0 released, I guess things may have been changed

Answer (score 0):

1) If you requesting token right after application startup, then some application initialization logic is being occured before the first execution of any controller method.
2) If you are using remote SQL server instance, this can cause long request processing. Try local profiling using local SQL server.